# angular async pipe not updating the view

Tags: angular, ngrx

My problem can be best described by analogy with the selectors example of the ngrx documentation to keep things simple (https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md#using-selectors-for-multiple-pieces-of-state).

I use the async pipe to subscribe to certain slices of state which I select using selectors, for instance

```
this.visibleBooks$ = this.store$.select(selectVisibleBooks)
```

The thing is that, if the `allBooks` array is "small", <100 items, my view gets updated instantly. But when it is large, >100, my view gets only updated next time change detection is triggered, for instance by scrolling. This is quite a bad user experience, to only see books once you scroll the list.

I looked at the source for async pipe (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts), and indeed the `_updateLatestValue` method calls `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()`, which as far as I understand marks the component to be checked for changes **the next time** change detection is triggered.

My current way around this is by subscribing manually within the top-level component

```
this.store$.select(selectVisibleBooks).subscribe(cb)
```

and calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` manually within the callback.

I find this however unsatisfactory and would simply like async pipe to always work, no matter how large the `Book[]` array. Does anybody have some suggestions or a correction with which I could make things work?

---

**edit as per request**

The "books store" case above, as said, was just an analogy for the app I'm writing to keep things simple. In reality, my app renders nodes and edges of a graph, where nodes and edges also have a version attached, denoted "vnode", which together with "vedge"s span a version tree. So any graph element has its own version tree.

What I am developing currently is a search form, where we send a certain request to the backend, asking it for any nodes which match a certain set of search key/value pairs.

So, those nodes would then be rendered in a component `<nodes-list>`, which we pass nodes by input binding

```
<nodes-list [nodes]="nodes$ | async"></nodes-list>
```

`nodes-list` has change detection "on push", while the top-level `<search>` component has default strategy.

`nodes$` is set within `ngOnInit()` as

```
this.nodes$ = this.store$.select(selectFullNodesList)
```

`selectFullNodesList` looks like this:

```
export const fullNodesSelector = getFullNodesSelector(createSelector(selectSearchState, s => {
    if (s.currentId) {
        const nodes = s.queries.get(s.currentId).nodes;
        if (nodes) {
            return [...nodes];
        }
    }
    return null;
}))

export const selectFullNodesList = createSelector(
    fullNodesSelector,
    (global: GlobalState) => global.data.counts,
    createSelector(selectSearchState, s => s.sort),
    (nodes, counts, sorting) => {
        if (!nodes || !counts || !sorting) return null;
        return [...nodes.sort(sorting.sortCbFactory(counts))];
    }
)
```

Let me explain:

- `getFullNodesSelector(...)` I will show below, it sits in a top-level library because we may reuse it in many features. But what it does is, it takes as an argument another selector which points to an array of node & vnode key pairs `{key: number, vKey: number}[]`, and turns that array into an array of nodes with their vnodes attached (see below how).
- So as you can see, the selector we pass it selects the state of our `search` feature, if there is a `currentId`, which is the id of the current request to the backend, then we select the nodes which were the result of our current request.
- `s.queries` is a light wrapper around a Javascript object, which allows me easily get/set values, clone, or add new items to a clone. This I find helpful when working with key/value stores in NGRX. Hence the `s.queries.get(s.currentId).nodes`.
- `global.data.counts` is simply a list of how many neighbors each node has. This I want to know because I'd like to sort the nodes list by "count".
- `s.sort` is which sorting of the list is currently selected.
- Note the use of `sortCbFactory`, this factory simply returns the correct callback to pass to `Array.sort`, but I need `counts` to be present in the local scope of the callback because otherwise I wouldn't be able to sort by counts.
- So, whenever nodes change (for instance a new version is referenced on the node), counts change (neighbors are added to a node) or sorting changes, the projection function is called, and a new nodes list is emitted.
- Note that we return a fresh array after sorting.

`selectSearchState` is simply a feature selector

```
export const selectSearchState = createFeatureSelector<SearchState>('search');
```

`getFullNodesSelector(...)` looks like this:

```
function getFullNodesSelector(keyPairsSelector: MemoizedSelector<object, GraphElementKeyPair[]>): MemoizedSelector<object, INodeJSON<IVNodeJSON>[]> {
    return createSelector(
        keyPairsSelector,
        (s: GlobalState) => s.data.nodes,
        (s: GlobalState) => s.data.vnodes,
        (pairs, nodes, vnodes) => {
            if (!pairs || !nodes || !vnodes) return null;
            return pairs.map(pair => ({
                ...nodes.get(pair.key),
                _SUB: {
                    ...vnodes.get(pair.vKey)
                }
            }));
        })
}
```

Some comments again:

- As you see, we pass a selector which points to an array of `GraphElementKeyPair` (`{key: number, vKey: number}`)
- We ask the global state for the nodes store and vnodes store
- We map all pairs to a fresh object.
- Note that nodes and edges are again the wrapper object mentioned earlier, which has a `get` method.

Thus, as we've subscribed to `this.nodes$` with the async pipe, each time there is a new event on the stream `<nodes-list>` should be updated. However, in practice it appears that this depends on the size of `INodeJSON<IVNodeJSON>[]`, and that if the array has length > ~80, we've got to trigger change detection manually by clicking somewhere or scrolling. nodes-list is refreshed automatically, as should be the case, for smaller arrays.

Comment: Are you any place using OnPush change detection? That seem to have effect of the kind (view getting refresh on next user activity) you are observing - https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/

Comment: Hi @WandMaker, yes, I am using onPush for "dumb" components.. So what you are suggesting is is that I probably should not use async pipe/onpush cd for "large" datasets, but for "small" it would be fine? I am a bit confused about this, because of the arbitrariness. I am also not using direct mutability, as I use ngrx-store-freeze which should guard me against that. So inputs are fresh references, as is indeed reflected in the behavior for "small" data sets. I have the feeling it's a problem with `markForCheck` of async pipe, which causes the fresh object at the comp. input not to be detected.

Comment: As far as I know, async pipe should work fine for small as well as large data sets.

Comment: Yeah, so this is also what confuses me... I have new object references at the inputs of child components, but somehow  when the array of "books" is large, my view only gets updated when I trigger cd. I'm now thinking of simply dropping async pipe, always subscribing manually in the parents, and always calling detectChanges().

Comment: @WillemvanGerven did you find a way for `async` pipe ? I'm at similar situation want to use `async` pipe instead of subscribing and triggering manual change detection.

Comment: @k11k2 Sorry for late reply. Above particular issue was caused by a meta reducer silently erroring. However, in general @maxime1992 is right: Check your selectors and make sure they return new object references. In particular make sure data related to your view is cloned, otherwise change detection might not pick up changes. So if your view relies of on a `carFactory` object with many `assemblyLine` members, and each assembly line is an array of `manufacturingStage` objects, and your view relies on a particular manufacturing stage object, *all* should be cloned, just like in reducers.

Comment: @k11k2 But to be frank, I've never gotten to warm up fully to the async pipe. I like the concept of it and how it cleans up component classes, and I want it to work for me. But somehow I've never gotten it to work as flawlessly, and as predictable and reliable as subscribing on the component class and calling `detectChanges()` manually. So I've stopped using it since I spend too much time ironing out all the peculiarities. It's probably just my noobishness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll not have any problem with large dataset. You selectors are **supposed** to be synchronous. Which means that when the selector is running, nothing else is happening in the background. Not matter how much time it takes to compute everything in your selector, you'll be fine. If it's taking too long, you might have a freeze in the browser but that's it.

When you say

> I use ngrx-store-freeze which should guard me against that

```
It is not true.
```

It is true from the store point of view. But let's picture the following:

Your store has an array of IDs (let say users IDs).

You have a first selector called `getAllUsers`.
This one is just mapping over the users IDs and retrieving the correct users, right? Signature would be `(usersIds: string[]): User[]`.

Of course here, you create a new array reference and you are not (supposed) to mutate the `usersIds` array.

But then, you've got an other selector. `getUsersResolved` which basically "resolve" foreign properties. Let say that a user has a list of animals. From the first selector you'll get a list of users and for each of them, an `animalsIds` properties. But what you want is to have an `animals` array instead. If from this selector you mutate the original array (the one coming from the first selector), `ngrx-store-freeze` will not throw any error, which make sense: You're mutating an array, but not the one from the store.

**So how could that be a problem?**

- Your component subscribe to `getUsersResolved`, assign that to a variable which is then subscribed to from the view using the `async` pipe (let's say it's the first time in the whole app that you're subscribing to it!)
- Your first selector `getAllUsers` is then called (for the first time) by `getUsersResolved` (also called for the first time)
- `getAllUsers` creates a new array as intended and passes it to `getUsersResolved`. As it's the first time, even if you modify that array into the `getUsersResolved`, you wont have any problem: Change detection will be done as it's the first time receiving the array
- Now imagine that your list of users **does not* change but the animals list changes. Your selector `getUsersResolved` will be triggered but in the case where you're not respecting immutability and modify the first array coming from `getAllUsers`, the array reference does not change and the change detection won't happen. And it's totally fine as that array is not part of the store, it was an array created from a selector

So I'm not sure whether your problem comes from there or not, but you might want to double check that you respect immutability within your selectors.

Eventually if you're not sure, please share the code of `selectVisibleBooks`, **and every selectors used by it**.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. You're indeed right. However, I checked my selectors and they *are* creating new objects. I have dropped the async pipe in favor of subscribing manually and calling `detectChanges`, in which case I have *zero* problems with change detection. So for me this is really strange. What is also funny is that if I dispatch the action which would trigger `allBooks` to be updated simply by calling it in `ngOnInit`, the problem goes away. But if I press the "Show books" button manually to dispatch the action myself, then the problems shows. No idea what's causing this.

Comment: Umh. Are you sure at least that you've binded the button correctly? Can you see the action dispatched with store dev tools? Sometimes it's simpler than what we think :)

Comment: Also, if you can share more code I might eventually be more helpful ;)

Comment: Hi @maxime1992, I've edited my question to include some details. Although I'm not sure it will help... Yes, the button is correctly bound, as like I said, for "small" result arrays there is no problem. So apparently "size matters"... :S

Comment: I have the feeling the problem can be traced to something screwing up the store, although I don't know what yet. When my results array is large - and thus when I have to click somewhere for my changes to be reflected - sorting for instance doesn't work anymore either. The action is dispatched, but never reflected in the view. Any ideas on how to debug such a case are much appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you using a library that might manipulate and update data coming from store? For example handling sorting for you and manipulating the first instance of creating and returning a new one?

Comment: Can you try to make a small repro on Stackblitz?

Comment: Really really to use :) https://stackblitz.com and then select Angular. You're good to go. You can also right click on a folder to generate a component, service etc. And on the left you can install NPM dependencies (ngrx for ex)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your willingness to help me out. But I've found out what went wrong, fortunately! I was dispatching an action which was passed a class instance of a request I was making to an API, to set certain properties on the state from it. I also have a meta reducer which logs all my dispatched actions. However, this logger didn't like to have to stringify this class instance passed to the action which references electron's IPCRenderer, and somehow silently errored, screwing more or less everything up.

Comment: Brilliant! Glad you solved it :) Thanks for letting me know